# How to connect splitted nodes to another node?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

Im currently trying to import a csv file in my neo4j database with movie-ids, directors and actors.
The csv it looks like this:

```
 |id|    directors   |           actors                |
 |33|Steven Spielberg|Tom Hanks; Brad Pitt; Tim Allen  |
 |34|John Lasseter   |Ryan Goslin; Brad Pitt; Tom Hardy|
```

My Problem: I am able to split the actors into seperated and unique nodes, but they aren't connected to the MovieIDs where they acted in.

After I set the unique constraints for movie id and director/actor names, my Cypherquery looks like this:

```
 LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM  
 'file:///C:/Users/Jens/Documents/SeminarDB/kleinefilmDB.csv' AS line
 CREATE (movie:Movie {id: TOINT(line.id)}) 
 MERGE (director:Director {name: line.director} )
 FOREACH (n IN SPLIT(line.actors, ";")| MERGE (actor:Actor {name: n}))

 CREATE (actor)-[:ACTED_IN]->(movie)
 CREATE (director)-[:DIRECTED]->(movie)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the relationship in the FOREACH.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM  
'file:///C:/Users/Jens/Documents/SeminarDB/kleinefilmDB.csv' AS line
CREATE (movie:Movie {id: TOINT(line.id)}) 
MERGE  (director:Director {name: line.director} )
CREATE (director)-[:DIRECTED]->(movie)   
FOREACH (n IN SPLIT(line.actors, ";")| 
         MERGE (actor:Actor {name: n})
         CREATE (actor)-[:ACTED_IN]->(movie)
        )
```